# No view found for id for fragment when replacing from Adapter

Tags: java, android, fragment, frame

I'm trying to replace my current fragment with another one. I'm doing this from the Adapter, since I wanna do it when clicking on a Card. This is my code into the adapter:

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (mMovieCategory.getImageUrl() != null) {
                try {
                    //TODO
                    FragmentTransaction ft = ((AppCompatActivity) v.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.movie_container, new Fragment_Movie());
                    ft.addToBackStack(null);
                    ft.commit();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onClick: Image url is not correct");
                }
            }
        });
```

In the replace function I used the id assigned to the fragment I want to invoke. This is the XML:

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/movie_container"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@color/list_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is the fragment I want to invoke:

```
package com.lab.movietime;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;

import static com.android.volley.VolleyLog.TAG;

public class Fragment_Movie extends Fragment {

    private static final String url = "https://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;

    public Fragment_Movie() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static Fragment_Movie newInstance() {
        Fragment_Movie fragment = new Fragment_Movie();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movie, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Movie movie = new Movie();
                                movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                                movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                                movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                                        .doubleValue());
                                movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));

                                // Genre is json array
                                JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                                ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                                for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                    genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                                }
                                movie.setGenre(genre);

                                // adding movie to movies array
                                movieList.add(movie);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();

            }
        });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
        return view;
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

> No view found for id 0x7f0900ab (com.lab.movietime:id/movie_container) for fragment Fragment_Movie{1f8531a}

Why? Is the id: **container_movie** incorrect?

Comment: share your activity layout

Comment: Did you tried with Callback from Adapter to Fragment class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `movie_container` is within the `Fragment`: You need to pass the ID of the container view in the `Activity`'s layout, not the ID of the `Fragment`'s view.

This will be the ID of the `View` *containing* the `Fragment`, as opposed to the `View` *contained within* the `Fragment`.